# Inserting information into 2 columns, but no rows are added and there are no errors?

Tags: python, mysql, sql-insert, mysql-connector

I have a Sign up/Sign in setup which inserts the username and password entered by the user to be stored in MySql. but when inserted there are no rows? or nothing gets inserted? the columns remain completely blank.
Also I'm using Tkinter as the GUI.

My MySql server has a basic setup and I haven't touched anything.

-Keep in mind I am very new to Python and MySql in general, so maybe I have made mistakes, but I just can't figure it out.

They stay just like this :

| Username | Password |
| --- | --- |
| --- | --- |

The block of code that does the inserting :

```
def SignUp():   

    NotEmptyEntry = len(PWE.get().strip()) != 0 and len(UNE.get().strip()) != 0

    if NotEmptyEntry:

        info_un = [UNE.get()]
        info_pw = [PWE.get()]
        
        Add_Info = ("""INSERT INTO Entries VALUES (%s,%s)""", (UNE.get(),PWE.get()))
    
        cursor.execute(*Add_Info)
        
        ErrT.config(text="Successfully created account.")

    else:
            ErrT.config(text="No Username/Password is entered.")
```

"UNE" stands for "Username entered"

"PWE" stands for "Password entered"

"ErrT" stands for "Error text"

Thank you for your help.

*NOTE : I have had several problems with writing this part so it might be a bit chaotic since I got a lot of help from the Internet. also English is not my first language, if there is any bad sentencing, that's why. and also this is my first question on this website.

I really cant figure it out and I don't know what's causing this, this question is my only choice right now,
I felt like this part of the code would be the easiest, its just a simple inserting! Or well I thought so.
I get no output (Error or not) with this code because it seems to work (I don't know), the only outputs I had were before I wrote this part and has nothing to do with inserting. and before you say it I have refreshed everything both in MySql and in Visual Studio Code, I even restarted my laptop 5 times, but to no avail. I dropped the table many times but still no difference. because of the purpose of the program I am writing, I need this to work so I'm kind of stuck.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Where is cursor variable defined? Where do you check if the insert statement was executed successfully?